# Where should test projects be placed?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

We have several solutions that use a project called **DogService**, and they have this added as a project reference inside of the solution.

If I want to create unit tests for **DogService** and call it **DogService.Tests**, where would I physically place this project?

**Should the unit tests for a project be included in every solution that references the project?**

Comment: IMO, they should be placed in the same solution as the DogService project. Projects that simply reference DogService.dll should not be testing the DogService project itself.

Comment: @itsme86 multiple solutions are referencing DogService as a project reference, should all the solutions get the test project as well?

Comment: The answer is purely opinion-based, but since you're using _project_ references and have the ability to change the code, then yes you should include the unit test project so you can update and run the unit tests when the code changes.

Comment: should the test project be located in the same physical dir as the dogservice proj?

Comment: Doesn't really matter about the physical location - normally I like to have it as a sibling folder to the project, but the .sln file is taking care of that for you so wherever makes most sense for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you work with DogService.  But if any change of dogservice can come from any of the solutions then each solution should add the unit tests.  In general structuring libraries like

```
    /Lib
       /DogService
          /DogService
          /DogServiceTests

   /MainProject/...
```

this is optimized to work well with :-

https://github.com/ingydotnet/git-subrepo

Also the continuous build tool then builds it as part of a pull request and runs the tests of all libraries so it can then be merged into the master of each library.

Alternatively, distribute your libraries as prebuilt assemblies using a private nuget repository.   If you do this, no need for the tests in each solution. The only downside of this is it can be a little more cumbersome to make changes across multiple libraries

Comment: if you do use gitsubrep, at this exact point in time, use branch `issue/142`